# How to remove "\" in logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am new to the Logstash, I need to remove `\` from `request` and `Http_method`

```
request": "\"GET https://www.vvvvvv HTTP/2.0""
http_method": "\"GET"
```

Expected results:

```
request": "GET https://www.vvvvvvv HTTP/2.0""
http_method": "GET"
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is an event that is being parsed from a log file, when you are processing your events, in the filter plugin, you can use the gsub in mutate filter plugin to process it appropriately.

```
filter
{

    mutate {

        gsub => ["message","[\\]",""]

    }


}
```

This would replace all the backslashes to empty string in the event.